# java multi-class package compile error

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, package

I'm working on a project where I create a class full of methods called Fraction.java, for which the package/project is named.  I have a second class in a different file called Tester.java that makes calls from the Fraction class.  When I completed it and went to compile, I got an error.  The Fraction.java class file compiled fine, but when I go to compile the Tester.java, command prompt throws

```
Tester.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
Fraction frac0 = new Fraction();
^
symbol:    class Fraction
location:  class Tester
```

It has one of those for every object I created in the Tester class.  The code runs fine in Netbeans with no errors, so what do I need to do to fix it?

For reference, this is what the Tester.java class looks like.

```
package fraction;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 9;
        Fraction frac0 = new Fraction();
        Fraction frac1 = new Fraction(54, 24);
```

and it goes on like that for more of them. What went wrong?

Comment: Read up about the classpath.

Comment: any documentation you could point me at?

Comment: Yes, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: I read the document, and both my system variables PATH and CLASSPATH are set to C:\Users\(myusername)\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Fraction\src\fraction where the Fraction.java class is stored along with Tester.java

Comment: You don't need to set PATH to that unless it contains executiable files, and you don't need to set CLASSPATH to that unless it is the root of a package-structured hierarchy of .class files. I suggest you stop guessing and have a proper look at the documentation.

Comment: I was not attempting guesswork, and was only trying to apply what I read in aforementioned documentation.  I appreciate the time you take to offer feedback, but I don't feel it necessary to be rude.  In any case, I have re-read the doc, and it doesn't sufficiently answer the question I have.  It simply covers setting those two paths, not troubleshooting compilation errors on a multi-class file package.

Comment: You didn't read anything about setting the PATH like that in the documentation. The question I would now ask is what command line you are using to compile these files, and what directory you're in when you're doing so.